# Storing LDAP Credentials

Tags: asp.net, ldap, web-config

What's the ideal way to store login and password for LDAP membership providers in the web.config?

Having the login and password stored in the provider under connectionUsername/connectionPassword attributes does not go well with me because, I would want to encrypt the connection string later on.

Don't have much experience with this, and was wondering if anyone had any best practices on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has tools built into the Framework for encrypting/decrypting sections of your Configuration files:

[Encrypting and Decrypting Configuration Sections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zhhddkxy.aspx)

And here's a walkthrough:

[Walkthrough: Encrypting Configuration Information Using Protected Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dtkwfdky.aspx)